# Questions for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$.

Tags: calculus

Consider the power series
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!} = 1+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}+\ldots
\end{equation*}
1. Show that the series converges absolutely for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
Remark: From this, it follows that its sum defines an infinitely differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, given by
\begin{equation*}
f(x) := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}.
\end{equation*}

This series does converge absolutely because
\begin{equation*}
\left|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\right| = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}
\end{equation*}
converges. To see that this does converge, we can use the ratio test. It follows that if we let $a_n = \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ then we get
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{\frac{x^{2(n+1)}}{(2(n+1))!}}{\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}}\right| \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{\frac{x^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!}}{\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}}\right| \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{x^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!}\times \frac{(2n)!}{x^{2n}}\right| \\
&= \left|x^2\right|\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{(2n)!}{(2n+2)!}\right| \\
&= \left|x^2\right|\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{2n\times (2n-1)\times (2n-2)\times \ldots}{(2n+2)\times (2n+1)\times 2n\times (2n-1)\times (2n-2)\times \ldots}\right| \\
&= \left|x^2\right|\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\right| \\
&= \left|x^2\right|\times 0 \\
&= 0 < 1
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Thus, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ converges by the ratio test and so $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ converges absolutely for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ as required.
2. Determine whether $f$ is even or odd.
$f$ is odd because
\begin{equation*}
f(-x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^{2n}}{(2n)!} = -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!} = -f(x).
\end{equation*}
3. Find the power series for the first and second derivatives of $f$.
Differentiating term-by-term gives the power series
\begin{equation*}
f'(x) = 0+\frac{2x^1}{2!}+\frac{4x^3}{4!}+\frac{6x^5}{6!}+\ldots = 0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2nx^{2n-1}}{(2n)!} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
f''(x) = \frac{2}{2!}+\frac{12x^2}{4!}+\frac{30x^4}{6!}+\ldots = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2n-1)x^{2n-2}}{(2n-1)!} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n-2}}{(2n-2)!}.
\end{equation*}
4. Is there a simple relationship between $f''$ and $f$?
Not sure about this one.
5. Show that $f$ is bounded below, i.e., there is an $m\in \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)\geq m$, $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, but is not bounded above, i.e., there is no $M\in \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)\leq M$, $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$.
 Since the sequence of partials sums defining $f(x)$ are increasing, we have
\begin{equation*}
f(x)\geq 1+\frac{x^2}{2!}.
\end{equation*}
Thus,  $f$ is not bounded above (since $x^2$ is not bounded above). How do I show its bounded below? I'm guessing because the former is true about not being bounded above.

Comment: You are wrong in part 2  ... $(-x)^{2n} \ne -(x^{2n})$

Comment: For part 4, get some help by writing down the first 3 terms in each of the series $f$ and $f''$.

Comment: For part 5.  I all the terms are positive, then of course it is bounded below by $0$.

Comment: Your argument for absolute convergence seems wrong.

Comment: Thanks. For part 4 $f(x)=1+f’’(x)$.

Comment: This function is even. The negative sign is under an even exponent. As for the relationship between the function and it’s derivative, they are the same! Take another careful look at your final sum for the second derivative. The $n=1$ term is a bit problematic but the rest can be rewritten if you write out some terms...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number of your answers are not correct.  If you have learned Taylor series you can see (by adding the appropriate Taylor series) that the series you're given is $\frac 12 (e^x + e^{-x}) = \cosh x$.  That will help you see what the correct answers should be.

For number $2$, it's not correct that $(-x)^{2n} = -(x^{2n})$.

For number $3$, you can simplify the expression for the second derivative by changing the lower limit of summation from $1$ to $0$ (and making the appropriate change inside the summation).

That should help you answer number $4$.

As for $5$, as long as $x$ is real, every term of your power series is positive, which tells you something about the sum.

Comment: I think my series for the second derivative is good because if I compare it to the series for the original function we see that they are the same which is what we need.